# Finding all subsets of a set, a DP solution?

Tags: algorithm, dynamic-programming, memoization

I came across this problem of finding the subsets of a set & I wanted to know if my algorithm is correct. I am using a recursive approach and a hash-table to store the subsets already calculated and say the input string is "ABCD":

1) My approach is to add individual characters as the hash keys and the subsets of the key so calculated as values. For example in my hash-table the entry for 'B' for the given input string would look like "B", "BC", "BD", "BCD". The function calls up the stack would then use these sub-strings to form further subsets. For example "AB", ABC", "ABD", "ABCD".

2) I use a for loop to iterate over the characters remaining and check if the subsets for the given character are in the hash-table, if not, I recurse and form the subsets and store them.

The idea of this algorithm is that I don't have to re-calculate the subsets already seen and the subsequent function calls are then truncated. For example A->C, A->D as all subsets of C and D are calculated when the for loop in 'B' is being executed.

Is my memoized algorithm correct? 
Even after I memoize will the run-time be O(2^n)? Thank you in advance for your responses. Pardon me if I have erred anywhere, your comments will surely help me improve. Thanks once again!

Comment: Run-time cannot be less then O(2^n), because there are 2^n subsets.

Comment: There is nothing to "find" IMO, it is already known what all the subsets are. You can decide to enumerate them (as you have done), but that's equivalent to counting from 0 to (2^n)-1.

Answer (score 0):

Your memorization algorithm seems correct. But complexity is greater than O(2^n) and depends on your hash-function.

It is a NP-complete problem. If size of n is big, then you can not memorize. But if n is small(like 20), then you can solve this kind of problem using dp(Bitmasking+dp).

I've shown iterative idea below.

```
for(i=0;i<(1<<n);i++){
   subset=""
   for(j=0;j<n;j++){
      if( (i&(1<<j)) != 0 ) //if jth character of binary i is 1, then add jth item 
        add jth item to subset
   }
   print(subset)
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.Arrays;
    import java.util.List;

    public class MainClass {

        static List<List<char[]>> list = new ArrayList<List<char[]>>();

        // static List<int[]> list1 = new ArrayList<int[]>();
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            List<char[]> list1 = new ArrayList<char[]>();
            char[] a = {'A','B','C','D'};
            generate(a, 0, 0, list1);

            for (List<char[]> l : list) {
                for (char[] b : l) {
                    for (char c : b) {
                        System.out.print(c + ",");
                    }
                    System.out.println();
                }
            }

        }

        public static void generate(char[] array, int offset, int index, List<char[]> list1) {
            if (offset >= array.length)
                return;
            char[] newArray = Arrays.copyOfRange(array, offset, index);
            list1.add(newArray);
            if (index >= array.length) {
                list.add(list1);
                offset++;
                index = offset;
                generate(array, offset, index, new ArrayList<char[]>());
            } else {
                index++;
                generate(array, offset, index, list1);
            }
        }
    }
```